# is there a way i can alter a wordpress theme to display posts from 2 different categories instead of the one that can be set in banner setting

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

The themes banner settings allow it to show posts of one category.
But i would like it to show posts of two different categories

Here is what i tried

```
if ( $newscard_settings['newscard_banner_featured_posts_1_hide'] === 0 ) {

$newscard_fp_1_cat = absint($newscard_settings['newscard_banner_featured_posts_1_post_categories']);

$post_type_fp_1 = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'post__not_in' => get_option('sticky_posts'),
    'post_type' => array(
        'post'
    ),
);
if ( $newscard_settings['newscard_banner_featured_posts_1_latest_post'] == 'category' ) {
    $post_type_fp_1 = array( 'category__and' => array(8,15), 'posts_per_page' => 2, 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'DESC'  );
}

$newscard_get_featured_post_1 = new WP_Query($post_type_fp_1);
```

But it does not display any thing.
Here is the original code

```
if ( $newscard_settings['newscard_banner_featured_posts_1_hide'] === 0 ) {

$newscard_fp_1_cat = absint($newscard_settings['newscard_banner_featured_posts_1_post_categories']);

$post_type_fp_1 = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    'post__not_in' => get_option('sticky_posts'),
    'post_type' => array(
        'post'
    ),
);
if ( $newscard_settings['newscard_banner_featured_posts_1_latest_post'] == 'category' ) {
    $post_type_fp_1['category__in'] = $newscard_fp_1_cat;
}

$newscard_get_featured_post_1 = new WP_Query($post_type_fp_1);
```

Comment: using category_and means it has to be in both categories could that be the problem? You may want $post_type_fp_1['category__in'] = array(8,15);

Comment: Thanks Willy, That works